# getting the function to include spaces when doing ciphertext

Tags: python

```
def dec(key, ciphertext):
    plaintext = ""
    for char in ciphertext:
        char_pos = ALPHABET.index(char)
        new_pos = (char_pos - key) % ALPHABET_SIZE
        dec_char = ALPHABET[new_pos]
        plaintext += dec_char
    return plaintext
```

Comment: what is the `ALPHABET`, what are the contents of it?

Comment: # global constants:
ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
ALPHABET_SIZE = len(ALPHABET)

Comment: Does your cipher **allow** a space?

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Actually you can use `ord('a')` to convert a string to int and `chr(97)` vice versa. No need to index anything yourself.

Comment: @knh190 Indeed, we can. But since the primary focus of this question is different then optimization of the code, I believe it wouldn't be that much of a concern in this case

Comment: Just in case you are missing it ;) doesn't hurt in either way.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a check for whitespace before getting char_pos

`if char == ' ':
    plaintext += ' '
    continue`

This would add the space in as is and continue to the next character in the loop. You can also extend this to check for other whitespace instead of literal spaces.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I tried this but it doesnt print the ciphertext with a space. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:-**

```
def dec(key, ciphertext):
    plaintext = ""
    for char in ciphertext:
        if char == ' ':
            plaintext += ' '
            continue
        char_pos = ALPHABET.index(char)
        new_pos = (char_pos - key) % ALPHABET_SIZE
        dec_char = ALPHABET[new_pos]
        plaintext += dec_char
    return plaintext
```

The above code when encountering a whitespace as a character in the string, appends it to the plain text string, and continues the process.

**SAMPLE INPUT:-**

```
print(dec(3, "abcdef zyx def"))
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:-**

```
xyzabc wvu abc
```